# Android pull to refresh listview footer not appearing correctly

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, android-overscoll

I tried to add overscroll footer and header in a listview. While using default overscroll header and footer the footer stretches from last item to listview's bottom.This happens when we have only one or two items.There is no problem when there is number of items.

I tried pull to refresh listview also
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

But when we scrolls up the footer is adding just below the place ,where list items ends.Not in listviews bottom